# Read speeds of USB3 Type-C vs eMMC in a cheap ultrabook

Tags: linux, usb, ultrabook

I'm interested in getting a cheap ASUS ultraportable to do some coding work while I am abroad. I do simple data analysis (python and R) and have the luxury of running any big analysis jobs on the servers at my company.

My question is: if I install my linux distro (say Ubuntu 16.04) onto a USB-C memory stick, will I get faster boot times, I/O, etc from this than from the internal eMMC chip? Would this be an acceptable workaround for the slow speeds of the eMMC?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Modern SoC found in cheap ultra-books use eMMC with 5.x specifications. The 5.+ interface can handle up to 400 MBytes/s data rate. In most cases the SoC would have a dedicated eMMC controller, having 8-lane parallel interface.

USB 3.0 sticks, in practice, are using the same eMMCs but with USB-to-MMC bridge.

It seems apparent that direct connection to eMMC IC is better than a connection coming over any bridge.

Of course, the performance will differ depending on eMMC chip internal architecture that is used in a particular device. But you will be hard pressed to find a USB 3.0 flash performing faster than 100MBps on writes and reads. All bets are that internal flash will work better for running OS.

Comment: Thanks! I sort of figured I couldn't get any speedup from this. Have to just search for an option with an empty 2.5in slot.